# What is the symplectic manifold whose Delzant polytope is a trapezoid?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties

What is the symplectic form on the manifold whose associated Delzant polytope is a trapezoid? I am trying to find it by using the Marsden–Weinstein theorem, but I have been unable to do so. If someone knows the symplectic form exactly, please describe it or provide a reference.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you told us how you think about the above toric symplectic manifold associated to a trapezoid (b.t.w. those are called Hirzebruch surfaces). This will ensure that the answer you get is most useful to you.

Comment: The torus action is (s,t)(z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3)=(st＊z_0,s＊z_1,s＊z_2,t＊z_3).I made a reduction space by using it and some text book said it can be idetifed to Hirzeburch surface by [z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3]→([z_1,z_2],[z_1＊z_3,z_2＊z_3,z_0]).

Comment: and Hirzebruch surface has Kahler form induced by CP^1×CP^2,the book said.but I can't find the symplectic form by made from Delzant construction.Delzant construction is using morment map  pull back a reguler and reduct it by torus action. I want to know my method is right or not.

Comment: sorry for my bad groummer and mistaking spells

Comment: I'd recommend that you have a look at Ana Cannas da Silva's *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry*.  It contains a thorough exposition of Delzant's theorem and the reconstruction process.  In fact, if I remember correctly, she explicitly computes the very examples that you are working on (trapezoids).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.First,I made symplectic mannifold by reading translated of the book.But I want the symplectic form by described on localcoodinate.Maybe it didn't say it.The way I try to find it Fubini study metric on CP^1×CP^2 by restricted on

Comment: Thank you for your reply.First,I made symplectic mannifold by reading translated of the book.But I want the symplectic form by described on localcoodinate.Maybe it didn't say it.The way I try to find it Fubini study metric on CP^1×CP^2 by restricted on hirzeburch surface from Delzant polytope.I arithmatic that, but Fubini study could be not the same as pulled back standard symplectic form.My arithmatic could be wrong, but I tried it threetimes.